# SQL query Postgres 12

Tags: sql, postgresql-12

I'm doing an inner join on a table like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  patient p
INNER JOIN 
    vaccine v
ON 
    p.vaccine_id =  v.id
```

The condition `f.vac_1 =  mv.id` might not been satisfied in the case where a person have not been vaccinated. In such case, I don't want to ignore the row, but instead of displaying the vaccine name (which is the purpose of the inner join) to display an emtpy string.

How can this be done ?

**Example**

Table vaccinne

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Moderna |
| 2 | Comirnaty |
| 3 | Janssen |

Table patient

| id | name | vaccine_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1 |
| 2 | kermit | 2 |
| 3 | jessica |  |

I'm looking for a query to produce:

| id | name | vaccine_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | Moderna |
| 2 | kermit | Comirnaty |
| 3 | jessica |  |

Comment: What row?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, will add now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a `left join` starting with `foo`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo f LEFT JOIN
     vac v 
     ON f.vac_1 =  mv.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it work. Much appreciated!